# How to properly fix my git workflow

Tags: git

I'm currently programming a code that I need to deliver to a client (by putting it on a server), I want to have a correct workflow so I only give him what he needs (and what is currently working). Also, I'd like a branch for that client that is distinct to the master branch because we may later re-use this code with different features for others clients.

So if I correctly understand [this tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) or [this one](https://leanpub.com/git-flow/read) (very similar) I should have a branching looking like this :

```
(version)        0.1                 0.2  

Master            C'                 H''  
                  |                  |  
Client1           C'                 H''     
                  |                  |  
Release        C--C'             H'--H''  
               |   \             |  
Develop--A--B--C----C'-D----G----H'------I--J  
                        \       /  
Feature1                 E--F--H
```

My problem is that I started developing (and using git) without thinking at all of this way of working with flows. That means that currently, I have a master branch which is, in fact, my development branch...

So here are my questions :

1. Can I rename my master branch as a develop branch and then recreate a master branch? Or should I create a new branch named develop, push everything from the master one and start using the delveop branch as I used my master branch? (and only touch to the master branch when I have stable versions of my code ready for delivery)
2. I'm not sure I really understand how to correctly 'push' my work from a branch to another, I'd say by using `git merge` but whenever I see graphs showing what does merging it seems more like 'closing' a branch that updating it, is that the case? For instance, when I want to put the code from my release branch to master or client I want those branches to be available for future merges updates. Did I misunderstand the merging concept?
3. When working locally I should only stay in the develop, release, hotfix and features branches for modifying the code, right? (If I checkout to the master or client branch that would be only to update them ?)
4. Also when working locally, if I checkout to another branch before pushing to the distant repo, will I lose the changes I did ? (I'd say that if I used `git commit` I will find those changes when I check out again to the previous branch.)
5. Let's say I have my develop branch and my master branch, what are the commands I need to use to get this configuration? Is that possible to tag versions?

> ```
> (version)     0.1      0.2  
>
> Master         C        F     
>                |        |       
> Develop--A--B--C--D--E--F--H
> ```

Sorry for those newbie questions, I read and tried several tutorials but it is still very blurry in my mind and nobody on my team is using git. In fact, they kinda put me in charge to learn and promote it so I want to have a correct way to manage workflows and not throw everything away...

Thanks for your help and don't hesitate to ask if you need more precisions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I entirely understand the workflow you're shooting for.  The graph you've drawn isn't typical for a git commit graph, which in itself is ok, but this graph doesn't seem to represent the relationships between commits and branches in a way that can be accurate in git.  So I'll mostly have to take your word that you have found a more-or-less suitable workflow, and confine my answer to the direct questions you asked:

1) Because a branch is merely a pointer to a commit, you can easily rename `master` to `develop` and then recreate `master` wherever you want it.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b develop
git branch -d master
```

Be aware that once you create `master` somewhere else, it will likely appear to have moved in a non-expected way.  So if `master` had been pushed to a remote, the next attempt to push `master` will fail unless you use `push -f` (or, better, `push --force-with-lease`).  That will do a forced push, but doing a forced push will put all others who share the remote into a "broken" state, so some clean-up will need to be coordinated with them.  (Failure to coordinate this can result in your forced push being undone.)  See the `git rebae` docs under "recovering from upstream rebase".  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

2) Merging does not "close" a branch.  The source branch is unaffected by the merge.  The target branch either (a) moves to the commit indicated by the source branch (in the case of fast-forward), or (b) receives a new "merge commit" that incorporates the changes from the source branch.

3) Probably.  Again I don't know that your workflow's rules are fully explained for us to comment on this.

4) Once work is committed, it is very hard to lose it, even if it's only "locally" committed; that's the point of git

5) Again, these diagrams do not reflect the way commits and branches relate in git.  You could get something like

```
O ----------- MC ----------------- MH <--(master)
 \           /                   /
  A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- H <--(develop)
```

where `MC` and `MH` are merges of `develop` into `master`.  Note that the individual commits are still part of the history of `master` in this case.  You can sometimes "focus in" on just the commits on the "top line" of this diagram - i.e. `git log --first-parent master`; but if you share `master` with another repo, it gets everything.  Avoiding that is more complicated than just "creating the right branches".

There are several approaches to sharing ongoing updates with limited history.

One way is to keep a client branch that git thinks of as "unrelated" to the development history.  It might work like this:

You have whatever branch structure going on in your local repo, and you eventually merge to master a "version 1.0" that you want to share.

```
... V1 <--(master)
```

So you create the `client` branch like this

```
git checkout master
git checkout --orphan client
git commit -m "Version 1.0"
```

Now you have

```
C1 <--(client)

... V1 <--(master)
```

Now some more things happen locally, until you have Version 2.0

```
C1 <--(client)

... V1 -- V2 <--(master)
         /
    ... X
```

Now in the past I've worked out all kinds of schemes to keep track of what's already on the client branch, and/or figure the change from `V1` and `V2` so it can be applied to the client branch... but the truth is, if `V1` and `C1` match, then all you really care about is "how do I create a new commit `C2`, whose parent is `C1` and whose content (`TREE` object) matches `V2`?"

```
git checkout client
git merge $(git commit-tree -p client -m "Version 2.0" master^{tree})
```

Now you have

```
C1 -- C2 <--(client)

... V1 -- V2 <--(master)
         /
    ... X
```

If you ever incorporate patches from the client, that could take some additional thought.